# Highcharts modulo alternateGridColor

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

In HighCharts, is there a built-in method of getting functionally similar to 'alternateGridColor' to add a grid color to every third, fourth, etc row? Currently 'alternateGridColor' only allows you to color every second row.

This is the design I'm trying to accomplish:
[image: The design I'm trying to accomplish]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an automated way, but you can use plotBands to achieve your look.

```
var categories = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var plotBands = [];
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 1) {
    plotBands.push({
      color: '#fecdfe',
      from: i - .5,
      to: i + .5
    });
  } else if (i % 3 == 2) {
    plotBands.push({
      color: '#cdfee5',
      from: i - .5,
      to: i + .5
    });
  }
}
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  yAxis: {

  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: categories,
    plotBands: plotBands,
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],

  }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wskt4hzz/